# insert,update, delete derived entity in entity framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity

How do i insert an entity that is derived from another entity. here is my code but it's not working:(applicationreplacement derived from application

```
public void AddReplacementApp(Application entity,ApplicationReplacement rentity)
{            
     _ctx.CreateObjectSet<Application>().AddObject(rentity);
     _ctx.SaveChanges();    
}
```

Comment: I excausted google trying to figure out how to just insert a derived entity..I am using self tracking entities and created a repository for Application entity and declare context as ObjectContext _ctx then initializing that on repository constructor
ApplicationRepositoy(ObjectContext context)
{
_ctx= context;
}

I just need help saving a derived entity.Thankx

Comment: The code you show should work, so if you'd like help fixing your problem you will have to mention precisely what your problem is. It would also help to show how you've mapped `ApplicationReplacement`.